# TYPO3 9.5 repository query to fetch elements with multiple sys_categories

Tags: mysql, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to figure out how to write the following query to fetch some elements which have multiple categories.

```
$query->matching(
    $query->logicalAnd(
        [
            // the following 4 lines are the problem lines
            $query->logicalAnd(
                $query->in('categories.uid', $categories),
                $query->in('categories.uid', $countryCategories)
            ),
            // $query->in('categories.uid', $categories),
            // $query->in('categories.uid', $countryCategories),

            $query->logicalOr(
                [
                    $query->equals('is_pinned', 0),
                    $query->lessThan('pinned_until', time())
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
);
```

The idea is to fetch the elements where `categories.uid` match at least one uid in `$categories` and at least one in `$countryCategories`. Both `$categories` and `$countryCategories` are arrays filled with category uids.

The query worked fine until the second line `$query->in('categories.uid' [...]` was inserted. As soon as the second line is inserted the query result is empty. It's probably an error in the query, but neither me nor my colleague could find a working solution.

While searching I found the sql `UNION`, which I've never been working with before but I guessed it would be the way to go if I had to write the statement instead of building the query.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to fetch the elements with the "query builder" or if it is really necessairy to write a statement? If there is a solution with the query builder could you point it out for me? If not how would I build the query with `UNION` to fetch the elements as required?

If something is unclear, please do not hesitate to ask, I will try to specify further. Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

We've debugged the query too and I executed it in phpmyadmin directly. It was working without "`AND (sys_category.uid IN ( 41, 2 ))`" but with it the result is empty. The follwoing was the debugged query:

```
SELECT `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.* 
 FROM `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news` `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news` 
    LEFT JOIN `sys_category_record_mm` `sys_category_record_mm` ON ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`uid` = `sys_category_record_mm`.`uid_foreign`)  AND (( `sys_category_record_mm`.`tablenames` = 'tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news') AND ( `sys_category_record_mm`.`fieldname` = 'categories'))  
    LEFT JOIN `sys_category` `sys_category` ON `sys_category_record_mm`.`uid_local` = `sys_category`.`uid` 

    WHERE ((
            (`sys_category`.`uid` IN ( 15, 17, 10, 11, 12, 16, 13, 14 ))
            ////// this following line is where the problem begins
            AND (`sys_category`.`uid` IN ( 41, 2 ))
    )
/////////// the following lines are additional restrictions
/////////// which have no influence on the problem
        AND ((`tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`is_pinned` = 0) OR ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`pinned_until` < 1560867383))
    )
 AND ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`sys_language_uid` IN ( 0, -1) )  
 AND ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`pid` = 31)  
 AND ( ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`deleted` = 0)  
 AND ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`t3ver_state` <= 0)  
 AND ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`pid` <> -1)  
 AND ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`hidden` = 0)  
 AND ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`starttime` <= 1560867360)  
 AND ( ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`endtime` = 0)  
 OR ( `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`endtime` > 1560867360) ) )  
 AND ( ( ( `sys_category`.`deleted` = 0)  
 AND ( `sys_category`.`t3ver_state` <= 0)  
 AND ( `sys_category`.`pid` <> -1)  
 AND ( `sys_category`.`hidden` = 0)  
 AND ( `sys_category`.`starttime` <= 1560867360)  
 AND ( ( `sys_category`.`endtime` = 0)  
 OR ( `sys_category`.`endtime` > 1560867360) ) )  
 OR ( `sys_category`.`uid` 
 IS NULL) )  
 ORDER BY `tx_gijakobnews_domain_model_news`.`publish_date` DESC
```

If there's a missing bracket I problably removed it accidentally while formatting...

Comment: What is the result if you query only this:
`$query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                $query->in('categories.uid', $categories),
                $query->in('categories.uid', $countryCategories)
            )
        );
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($query->execute());
        die();
`

This should show a Debug output with your result

Comment: the query result is empty ---> added to the question

Comment: If you take a look into the database of one record you think that should be found by this query - what is inside the field `categories` ?

Comment: it's actually an mm-relation. In the categories field is only the amount of linked categories. I've already written a query in the database (with join) where I could see if the categories were really correct and they were. At least one element should have displayed...

Comment: And if you try for debuggen to manually set UIDs and make sure that there are existing ones in the list?
`$query->in('categories.uid', [1,5,8,12, .... ])`

Comment: Sadly we've already tried this too. I have the feeling that the problem lies within the second `$query->in()`-statement. I've tried the real query directly in the database but as soon as it has the second limitation of the categories the result is always empty. That's why I guessed that the problem lies within the repeated restriction of one and the same field... and that it's probably not a problem with the query builder but with the query itself...

Comment: You could write the query a bit more complicated with the QueryBuilder:

Following is not correct - I post it as an answere:

`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder::class)->select('*')->from('table')->where('where....')->execute()->fetchAll();`

Comment: We'll have a look at it and I'll report back. Thanks already for your support. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it way simpler in the end.

Instead of adding both restrictions by the query, I looped through the results restricted by the first `sys_category`-condition and then removed those which didn't meet the second `sys_category`-restrictions.

*Repository*

```
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd([

            $query->in('categories.uid', $categories),
            $query->logicalOr(
                [
                    $query->equals('is_pinned', 0),
                    $query->lessThan('pinned_until', time())
                ]
            ),
        ])
    );
```

*Controller*

```
public function getRestrictedNews($news, $countryCategories) {
    $newNews = array();

    foreach ($news as $newsItem) {
        $newsCategories = $newsItem->getCategories();
        $shouldKeep = false;
        foreach ($newsCategories as $categoryItem) {
            if (in_array($categoryItem->getUid(), $countryCategories)) {
                $shouldKeep = true;
            }
        }

        if ($shouldKeep) {
            array_push($newNews, $newsItem);
        }
    }

    return $newNews;
}
```

It may not be the best solution, but it's one that works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the where clause is applied on a "per row" basis.

Meaning If you have a query like the following (based off of your query):

```
SELECT *
FROM news
LEFT JOIN sys_category_record_mm mm
  ON (news.uid = mm.uid_foreign) /* AND (...) */
LEFT JOIN sys_category
  ON mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
WHERE
  sys_category.uid IN (1,2,3)
  AND sys_category.uid IN (4,5,6)
```

You might have one news entry, that is in category 1 and in category 4. But the result set would be two distinct rows:

```
news.uid | sys_category.uid
1        | 1
1        | 4
```

and the WHERE clause filters both of them out, because the sys_category.uid is not **both** in (1, 2, 3) **and** in (4, 5, 6) for each row individually.

The way to do that on an SQL level, would probably be, to do two joins to sys_category. But I do not believe it's possible with the (rather simple) extbase query builder.

*Edit:*

As a solution, you could use the `$query->statement()` method, that allows to use custom sql queries.

```
$result = $query->statement('SELECT news.* FROM news');
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Comment: I think you might have a point... I hoped that I wouldn't have to write the statement as it's quite lenghty and not so simple... Have you ever worked with `UNION` in an sql-statement and would this be the way to go?

Comment: I'd probably use OR instead, and filter the rest manually using php.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own custom Query with the QueryBuilder. Something like this:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;


$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
    ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table_to_select_from');

$result = $queryBuilder->select('*')
        ->from('table_to_select_from')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('field', ['1','2','3'])
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

DebuggerUtility::var_dump($result);
```

Here's the documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html